# downloading and uploading from usb

Tags: usb

i have a Dell inspiron-15-3552 with a 64bit OS
the OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
i bought a Sandisk Cruiser Blade Flash Drive 16GB to download and upload music,photos and files,will this Drive work with Ubuntu or if not which usb flash drive works with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Every modern USB drive will work with Ubuntu, unless it is physically broken. You just need to connect it to you PC and format it. System will suggest the settings. After formating it will appear as external drive.

Comment: Most are already formatted. No additional format needed. 64GB+ drives may require exFAT support to be installed. FAT32 is the default for any other smaller driver.